# A formula to transfer information in Column A to Column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, phpexcel

Any help would be much appreciated.

I need a formula to transfer information from Column A to Columns B and C.

Column A is currently listed like this:

```
Row 1 Contact
Row 2 Address
Row 3 Number

Row 5 Contact 
Row 6 Address
Row 7 Number
```

Etc.

I need it to read like this:

```
     Column A   Column B  Column C

Row 1 Contact   Address   Number
Row 2 Contact   Address   Number
```

I have a spreadsheet with about 3,000 rows of information so to move it by hand would take forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution is to filter to delete blank rows, copy ColumnA into ColumnB and into ColumnC. Delete top cell from ColumnB and top two cells from ColumnC with Shift cells up in each case.

Add a formula such as:

```
=MOD(ROW(),3)
```

in a spare column Row1 copied down to suit then filter that column to select `0` and `2` and delete all visible rows except Row1.

Comment: This is the standard solution